# C printf data format requirements

Tags: c

If I need to print an integer, what happens if I use %f instead of %d? or %ld instead of %d. Do I have to use the same print format as the real data?

Thanks,
Zack

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the specifier and the data have to match under penalty of Undefined Behaviour.

Quote from C99 Standard:

> > If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1p9

Answer (score 1):

You will invoke undefined behavior.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/docs/rr/dr_083.html

> (c11, 7.1.4p1) "If an argument to a function has [...] or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier and the argument type have to match, otherwise the behavior is undefined (meaning anything from garbage output to demons flying out your nose).

The format specifier doesn't just tell `printf` how to format the output; it tells the function what the *type* of the argument is.  `printf` is a variadic function, and as such it doesn't know the types of the arguments being fed to it ahead of time (except for first argument, which is always `const char * restrict`). The remaining arguments are just a wall of bytes on the stack.  Each conversion specifier tells `printf` how big each argument is (i.e., a 1-byte `char`, or a 2-byte `short`, or a 4-byte `float`, etc.) so it can grab the correctly-sized chunk of memory and interpret it correctly.